# UITableView Transparent BackGround

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

I got this code :

```
UIViewController *nextQuestionView = [[QuizzQuestionViewController alloc]init];
    nextQuestionView.view.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:0.44 green:0.44 blue:0.41 alpha:1];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:nextQuestionView animated:YES];
    NSLog(@"gotonextQuestion");
    [nextQuestionView newQuestion];
    [nextQuestionView release];
```

And i want to remove the black corner.

Thanks.

Comment: Hmmm I don't see any black corner, can you show us a screenshot?

Comment: I found my mistake. I didn't apply clearColor to the good tableView.